# Laravel how to display content based on publish date

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple Posts in my `laravel`-application which I want to display based on their publish date.

So when I create a post I set the publish date gets saved in this format `2019-06-27 12:00:00` in the `publishes_on`-column in the DB.

In my blade view I used to loop through the posts like this:

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
  <div>
      <h1>{{ $blog->title }}</h1>
      // etc. etc.
  </div>
@endforeach
```

So, when I forexample set the publish date to `2019-07-21 10:00:00` The post should not be displayed until the publish date has passed.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of that, you fetch those blogs which are less than current date,

```
Blog::where("publishes_on","<=",Carbon::now())->get();
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again mate :-)

Answer (score 2):

You want to filter out the posts in the controller.
Do not filter out in the view unless you plan to use unpublished posts elsewhere.

Something like:

```php
$blogs = Blog::where('publishes_on', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this a couple of different ways, the most performant way is at the database level. You could make your query something like:

```php
$blogs = Blog::where('publishes_on', '<=', now())->get()
```

You could also abstract this out if you would prefer to a query scope. In order to do this add the following method on your model.

```php
public function scopePublished($builder)
{
    $builder->where('publishes_on', '<=', now());
}
```

This will then allow you to change it to:

```php
$posts = Blog::published()->get()
```

That way the only posts you will be passing to your view will be those that are published.

### Option 2

The second option would be to compare the date/time within the view. For example:

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
  @if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($blog->publishes_on)->gte(now()))
    <div>
        <h1>{{ $blog->title }}</h1>
        // etc. etc.
    </div>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

However this way won't be as performant. This is because you are comparing dates and times on the PHP side for each iteration. The more posts that you are displaying the longer it will take for the page to load.

### Conclusion

It's probably best to do this on the database level. Using just a where clause is fine, but a query scope can make it slightly more readable.

I hope this helps.